# Clicking dynamic dropdown div with Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having problems with specifying the first element's xpath from a dynamically generated dropdown. I would like Selenium to click the first suggestion from dropdown on [this webpage](https://bilkom.pl/) after putting in some text. However, the way I want to locate it results in `NoSuchElementException`. My code:

```
public static void printTickets() throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", CHROMEDRIVER_PATH);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://bilkom.pl/");

    // hide iframe
    WebElement closeFrameButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-body']//button[@class='close']"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(closeFrameButton));
    closeFrameButton.click();

    // fill first field
    WebElement textInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fromStation']"));
    textInput.sendKeys("Warszawa");
    String firstElementXPath = "//div[@id='fromStation-cg']//div[@class='tt-dataset']//div[1]";
    WebElement firstElementDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath(firstElementXPath)); //NoSuchElementException
    firstElementDiv.click();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below xpath to select the 1st item from the dynamic list.

```
(//div[@id='fromStation-cg']//div[@class='tt-station tt-suggestion tt-selectable']//span)[1]
```

Checked the below piece of code which is working as expected.

```
// fill first field
    WebElement textInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fromStation']"));
    textInput.sendKeys("Warszawa");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    String firstElementXPath = "(//div[@id='fromStation-cg']//div[@class='tt-station tt-suggestion tt-selectable']//span)[1]";
    WebElement firstElementDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath(firstElementXPath)); //NoSuchElementException
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(firstElementDiv));
    System.out.println(firstElementDiv.getText());
    firstElementDiv.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is the xpath that you've provided. There's no 
`< div class="tt-dataset">`
Tag shown for any suggestions that you are getting after any search

`<div class="tt-station tt-suggestion tt-selectable">`

For selecting the first suggestion, you can use `findElements`.

```
WebElement textInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fromStation']"));
textInput.sendKeys("Warszawa");
List<WebElement> suggestionList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='tt-station tt-suggestion tt-selectable > span > i']"));
suggestion.get(0).click();
```

If you want to click on any other element, you can give the index number according to your need.